# Sort an ArrayList of Objects in C#

Tags: c#, arraylist, sorting, icomparable

How can I sort an `ArrayList` of objects? I have implemented the `IComparable` interface while sorting the `ArrayList`, but I am not getting the required result.

My code sample:

```
public class Sort : IComparable
{
    public string Count { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        Sort objCompare = (Sort)obj;
        return (this.Count.CompareTo(objCompare.Count));
    }
}
```

Here I want to sort the `ArrayList` based on `Count`.

Comment: @Srikanth Tell us which .NET version you're using for your development :) (re-tag your question for this).

Comment: "i am not getting the required result" is not enough information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and update your question. Also, do you *have* to use `ArrayList` rather than `List<T>`? Non-generic collections are, like, so 2004.

Comment: What result do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: "string Count" : potential defect.  "11" comes before "3"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
public class Sort : IComparable<Sort>
{
    public string Count { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual int CompareTo(Sort obj)
    {
        return (Count.CompareTo(obj.Count));
    }
}
```

as Count is string, it may not sort the way you expect....

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k6e334t.aspx):

> To perform a stable sort, you must implement a custom [`IComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx)
>   interface to use with the other overloads of this method.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use a LINQ construct to get a sorted version of your list, like so:

```
var results = myArrayList.OrderBy(x => x.Count).ToList();
```

Is there a reason you are not using LINQ (yet)?

Comment: This doesn't compile and gives the error

`Error CS1061 'ArrayList' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no accessible extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a first argument of type 'ArrayList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: See correct answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/852490/74585