# Get next highest number in an ObservableCollection column

Tags: c#, linq, observablecollection

I have a working line of code that retrieves the highest integer from a column in an ObservableCollection.

```
int highscore = dataAccess.GamePlayers.Max(t=> t.TotalScore);
```

I need a way to to retrieve the "next highest" integer from the same column. How could I achieve this with minimal code?

Comment: In SQL it would be: "SORT DESCENDING" and "TOP 2".

Comment: However, the question seems odd. If oyu got a Observaible Collection, you propably use WPF. If so, why would you need to math out the 2nd highest number? What is the purpose of that operation? Why is the stuff just not sorted in the Display, so the user can select it?

Comment: Order by descending, skip the first number and get the next one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the second maximum number in an array with the smallest complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810444/find-the-second-maximum-number-in-an-array-with-the-smallest-complexity) The same approach can be used for observable collection

Comment: None of these helped. I am not using an array. My question clearly says ObservableCollection.

Comment: var sndHighest = dataAccess.GamePlayers.Where(x => x < highscore).Max();